# Turning On Camera and LED Together

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, android-camera

I want to turn on the camera along with the LED flashlight using code.

This snippet turns on the LED Flash

```
c = Camera.open();
Parameters p = c.getParameters();
p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
c.setParameters(p);
c.startPreview();
```

And this line uses an Intent to start the camera.

```
i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

However,they don't seem to work together, i.e. either only the camera works or only the flash.

Could anyone please help me out ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)` starts the Camera application.

You don't need that. Instead you need to take a picture using your camera (since you have set special params to it).

So, use `Camera.takePicture` as shown here

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

Comment: But I don't want to use a SurfaceHolder. I actually have an ImageView to which the captured image is retrieved after the camera has clicked the picture. The intent camera is easy to start so I wanted to start the flash in that way only. Is this possible ?